# call of overloaded function is ambiguous (two function in different scope)

Tags: c++, overloading

code:

```
namespace asd {
    class A { };
    void f(A &a) { }
}

void f(asd::A &a) { }

int main() {
    asd::A instance;
    f(instance);
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
D:\>g++ -Wall -std=c++98 -pedantic a.cpp
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:10:12: error: call of overloaded 'f(asd::A&)' is ambiguous
a.cpp:10:12: note: candidates are:
a.cpp:6:6: note: void f(asd::A&)
a.cpp:3:7: note: void asd::f(asd::A&)
```

why does the compiler search the function 'f' in namespace asd's scope?
why is this called overloading? this is two different functions.
i would understand the error if the main funcion was like this:

```
int main() {
    using asd::f;
    asd::A instance;
    f(instance);
    return 0;
}
```

and i would get an error... but with this i dont...

this situation is same as when i do this?

```
std::cout << str;
// meaning 1:
std::operator<<(std::cout, str);
// meaning 2:
::operator<<(std::cout, str);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
using asd::f;
```

you tell the compiler "when I use the symbol `f` in the current scope, I actually mean `asd::f`". That's why it works.

As for the first case, it's because the compiler looks in the scope of the type of `instance` (that is `asd`) as well as the global scope. It's called [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup).

Comment: I believe you've meant `using`

Comment: but when i dont write "using asd::f;" why does not the complier know which one to call? when i call f(), i call f() and not asd::f()
(in a normal situation)

Comment: oh. i see. it depends on the arguments as well

Answer (score 1):

C++ does an argument dependent lookup. This means if you have an argument of a particular class type for a function, then to find the function the compiler will lookup function name in the namespace containing the argument's type.

In the following code, you have specified instance as variable of `class A` which is namespace `asd`

```
int main() {
    asd::A instance;
    f(instance);
    return 0;
}
```

Hence it will lookup for `f` in the `asd` namespace as well. To resolve this use:
`::f(instance);` for calling `f` in global namespace or `asd::f(instance);` in `asd` namespace.

This is called **koenig lookup**. Go to this [link](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/030.htm), if you want to understand more.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the compiler search the function 'f' in namespace asd's scope?

Argument-dependent lookup. The argument type `A` is scoped in `asd`, so that namespace is also searched for suitable overloads.

> why is this called overloading? this is two different functions.

That's exactly what overloading means: two functions with the same name but in different scopes, or taking different parameters.

> this situation is same as when i do this?

Yes, it could mean either; but since there is no `::operator<<`, there is no ambiguity.